# Подсчет количества повторяющихся элементов в двумерном списке Python 3.x?

Tags: python-3.x, двусвязный-список

На ввод дается определенное число и по его количеству создается тоже количество строк которые записываются с разделением по знакам в двумерный список. Пример ввода:

```
3
Зенит;3;Спартак;1
Спартак;1;ЦСКА;1
ЦСКА;0;Зенит;2
```

Результат:

```
[['ЦСКА', '0', 'Зенит', '2'], ['Спартак', '1', 'ЦСКА', '1'], ['Зенит', '3', 'Спартак', '1']]
```

Код выполняющий данное действие:

```
a = int(input())
b = [[input()] for i in range(a)]
c = []
for i in b:
    c.append(i[0].split(";"))
```

Как посчитать количество игр команд, путем подсчета названий команд в этом двумерном списке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Список уже есть, останется его обработать:

```
from collections import defaultdict

items = [['ЦСКА', '0', 'Зенит', '2'], ['Спартак', '1', 'ЦСКА', '1'], ['Зенит', '3', 'Спартак', '1'], ['ЦСКА', '2', 'Спартак', '2'], ['ЦСКА', '2', 'Зенит', '2']]

counter = defaultdict(int)
for x in items:
    counter[x[0]] += 1
    counter[x[2]] += 1

print(counter)

# Вывести с сортировкой
for name, number in sorted(counter.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True):
    print(name, number)
```

Консоль:

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'ЦСКА': 4, 'Зенит': 3, 'Спартак': 3})
ЦСКА 4
Зенит 3
Спартак 3
```